# Alternative Anomaly Detection Engine for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, machine-learning, anomaly-detection

I am searching for an alternative anomaly detection/machine learning engine on top of Elasticsearch. I know there exists the Machine Learning feature of Kibana but only in the Platinum Edtition.

Are they any alternatives of the Kibana ML as open source or for free that can be run localy?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few alternatives listed here: https://sematext.com/blog/x-pack-alternatives/#elasticsearch-machine-learning-alternatives-7

One of them is [Knowi](https://www.knowi.com/) and the other is [Sematext](https://sematext.com/).

And just yesterday, AWS released a fully open source version of ES with security and alerting plugins. No ML yet, but I would watch this project very carefully because knowing AWS is behind this, an ML plugin must not be that far away in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that this are cloud solutions. I search for systems that run on premise.

Comment: Hi @ssd_rider. Did you find any solution for on-prem ?